# Why am I getting an error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"?

Tags: java, c, ubuntu

I am executing java class in c program. It seems that everything is correct. But, I am getting an error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class subtract.java**

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: subtract.java**

There is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Usage: domath arg1 arg2\n");
    exit(0);
    }
    else if (fork()==0) {
    execlp("python3","python3","add.py",argv[1],argv[2],NULL);
    exit(0);
    }
    else if (fork()==0) {
    execlp("java","java","subtract.java",argv[1],argv[2],NULL);
    exit(0);
    }
    else if (fork()==0){
    execlp("node","node","multiply.js",argv[1],argv[2],NULL);
    exit(0);
    }
    else if (fork()==0) {
    execlp("bash","bash","divide.sh",argv[1],argv[2],NULL);
    exit(0);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    wait(NULL);

    printf("parent: done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

There is my Java code:

```
public class subtract {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("java: %s - %s = %d\n", args[0], args[1], Integer.parseInt(args[0])-Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    }
}
```

What is wrong there?

Comment: I have tried to execute java program separately. It works well. I have set the path to JAVA_HOME. What could be a cause of this error?

Comment: it would appear it can't find your class. from which path are you trying to start it? on which path are you trying to start it? have checked that that class exists on that path?

seeing as you are not experienced with Java code, or so it seems, with the disregard of naming conventions, why try to mix C with Java?

Comment: Because you cannot execute *java* code directly from command line like `java <file.java>`. You need to compile it first using `javac <file.java>` and then do `java <class_name_with_main_method>` to run the java code.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha, I did it.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha since the OP stated if he runs the code on it's own, it works, we can assume it's already compiled

Comment: @AltynbekAmirzhanov, then you need to remove the `.java` sufffix from the command you are trying to execute. Just `java <class_name>`.

Comment: change this : `execlp("java","java","subtract.java",argv[1],argv[2],NULL);` to `execlp("java","java","YourClassName",argv[1],argv[2],NULL);`

Comment: @PandeyAmit, Do you mean compiled java class or just java program?

Comment: @AltynbekAmirzhanov when compiling you need to add ".java" at the end of the command, when running, you don't

Comment: @Stultuske, Thank you very much! It worked.

Comment: @AltynbekAmirzhanov I mean compiled one. for compilation from your program I think you can use like below before execution. `execlp("javac","javac","subtract.java",argv[1],argv[2],NULL);`

Comment: @PandeyAmit, Ok, thank you, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all apply the path because this program work well  i have no error get no error in this program but if not set path then try to set path first and then run the program
thank you for your question

Comment: These are my paths: `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/altynbek/Desktop/SP"`,
`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"`. My programs are in Desktop/SP folder. Everything is ok with them?

Comment: in your path just add semicolon and dot operator at last and save that path